# DataTable rows not highlighting

Tags: html, css, datatables

I have a datatable, which displays all of the information correctly, and works fine until i add the row highlighting code  Rows with the value PV PLUS should highight green but they don't.

Also when i added my exact same code to JSFiddle all of the formating has gone even though i have linked to the cdn files, I think the problem is possibly the way i have placed the two items of jquery together, but i am not getting and errors from JS Fiddle abd so wondered if there was some other problems

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxdofh8e/)

CSS

```
table.dataTable tr.highlight {
  background-color: lime; 
  }
```

Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#example').dataTable( {
"aoColumns": [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    { "sType": "date-uk" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
     ]
    });  
   } );

  jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "date-uk-pre": function ( a ) {
  var ukDatea = a.split('/');
  return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1;
     },

    "date-uk-asc": function ( a, b ) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },

"date-uk-desc": function ( a, b ) {
   return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
     }

   } );
   fnRowCallback: function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
   if (aData[3] == "PV PLUS") {
       $(nRow).addClass('highlight');
      }
   }
```

HTML Table Code

```
          <table id="example">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Telephone</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Sales rep</th>
                    <th>Survey Date</th>
                    <th>Install Date</th>
                    <th>Sales Date</th>
                    <th>Payment</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Telephone</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Sales rep</th>
                    <th>Survey Date</th>
                    <th>Install Date</th>
                    <th>Sales Date</th>
                    <th>Payment</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                      <td>Lee Jones</td>
                      <td>32 road street</td>
                      <td>01268 413657</td>
                      <td>PV PLUS</td>
                      <td>£ 12,000</td>
                      <td>John</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <td>Simon Walker</td>
                      <td>34 road street</td>
                      <td>01268 413857</td>
                      <td>PV PLUS</td>
                      <td>£ 18,000</td>
                      <td>John</td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                      <td></td>
                     </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Are you included jquery CDN first?

Comment: on my page yes, in the js fiddle i have just added them as external resources, and nothing seems to happen

Comment: I changed CDN http request to https. it works well.
https://jsfiddle.net/under_09/yfcsvmn3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with your example (missing jQuery, styles). However the main reason the rows were not highlighted is that you have to use `!important` directive.

```
table.dataTable tr.highlight,
table.dataTable tr.highlight td {
    background-color: lime !important; 
}
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxdofh8e/3/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: That was it, i have been pulling my hair out since yesterday and never even thought of that.  Thanks

Comment: @StanWilliams, added better CSS rule to color column being sorted as well.

Comment: When i added it to my website it didn't work, but i noticed in your example it doesn't have the javascript code for the column sorting

Comment: OK i noticed i added it to the code above but not the jsfiddle.